# NPM package: best practices and exposing multiple import paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, package.json

I created an NPM package that uses Webpack and Babel for transpiling/bundling.

In my `package.json`, I've got main set to `"main": "build/index.js"`. And in my Webpack config, I have entry set to `entry: { app: './src/index.js' }`. My entry file is shown below.

Everything works fine when the package is installed. However, with this setup, two import paths are exposed for every helper:

This is a problem for editors that support auto imports, since they will sometimes auto import from `'my-package/build/utils/helper1'` rather than the preferred path of `'my-package'`.

**So, two questions:**

1. Is there any way to prevent the longer import path from being exposed?
2. What is considered best practice when creating NPM packages. Is my setup acceptable, or should I be doing something different?

**Entry File:**

```
import helper1 from './utils/helper1';
import helper2 from './utils/helper2';

export {
  helper1,
  helper2,
};

const myPackage = {
  helper1,
  helper2,
};

export default myPackage;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you can utilize [Webpack resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)
2. I often use the first way:

```
export {
  helper1,
  helper2,
};
```

Recently, I found that we can use [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to export. This is a good [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/elegant-patterns-in-modern-javascript-ice-factory-4161859a0eee).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest probably merge your `helper1` and `helper2` in one file and name it `helpers`, then you can put them in the `class` `myPackage` so that you then export them as a module like this

```
import myPackage from './utils/helper';
// OR import {helper1, helper2} from './utils/helpers';


export default class myPackage {
      helper1,
      helper2,
};
```

OR

```
import {myPackage} from './utils/helpers';    
// OR import {helper1, helper2} from './utils/helpers';


module.exports.myPackage = (helper1, helper2) => {
  this.helper1 = helper1;
  this.helper2 = helper2;
};
```

I hope this helps.